# Protect some cells in an excel worksheet

Tags: excel

Good day,

Im almost completed with my data tool which i am going to send to our offices across the country. i will like to ensure that most of the information stays the same. in order to do this, i will like to lock some cells on all the pages on my sheet.

i reseached online and there were suggestions about locking the cells and then protecting the page. however, when i do that, i cant edit ALL the cells on the prpotected page. is there a way to protect only some cells so that they are untouchable and some are edittable?

thanks

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a

Answer (score 1):

You must unlock the cells that should stay editable after protecting the sheet. You can do that in the Formating Cells Dialog. First select the cells you want to format. Then press {ctrl + 1}. On the protection tab, deselect the locked option. Then protect the sheet.